# Inserting values of different fields of a row into one column of another table in certain order

Tags: sql, t-sql

When i am inserting fields from table T_EMP_MASTER into temp table , it's appearing in #temp_empdet as per the order of values of emp_id,emp_id2,emp_id3 .
I want  emp_id,emp_id2,emp_id3 fields to to be inserted as per the order of insertion, like

```
1. emp_id   
2. emp_id2   
3. emp_id3
```

How can I do the same here , using same insertion with union or using anything else ?

```
 CREATE TABLE #TEMP_EMPDET
 (SN INT,EMP_ID INT)

 INSERT INTO #TEMP_EMPDET
 SELECT EMP_ID FROM T_EMP_MASTER WHERE CODE = @CODE
 UNION
 SELECT  EMP_ID2 FROM T_EMP_MASTER WHERE CODE = @CODE
 UNION
 SELECT  EMP_ID3 FROM T_EMP_MASTER WHERE CODE = @CODE
```

Comment: Table rows represent *unorered* sets of data. There is no inherent ordering in records returned by a query like `select * from empdet`, unless you do specify and `order by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to guarantee the order of insertion, use three separate statements:

```
INSERT INTO #TEMP_EMPDET (EMP_ID)
    SELECT EMP_ID FROM T_EMP_MASTER WHERE CODE = @CODE;

INSERT INTO #TEMP_EMPDET (EMP_ID)
    SELECT  EMP_ID2 FROM T_EMP_MASTER WHERE CODE = @CODE;

INSERT INTO #TEMP_EMPDET (EMP_ID)
    SELECT  EMP_ID3 FROM T_EMP_MASTER WHERE CODE = @CODE;
```

Because SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, you will only see the "ordering" in an identity column or if `EMP_ID` is a clustered key.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_EMPDET (
    EMPDET_ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    SN INT,
    EMP_ID INT
);
```

Your code is not inserting values in order specifically because of the `UNION`.  That eliminates duplicates and re-arranges the data.  If you want that functionality, things get a bit more complicated.  I think I would recommend:

```
INSERT INTO #TEMP_EMPDET
    SELECT v.EMP_ID
    FROM T_EMP_MASTER EM CROSS APPLY
         (VALUES (1, EMP_ID), (2, EMP_ID2), (3, EMP_ID3)
         ) V(WHICH, EMP_ID)
    WHERE CODE = @CODE
    GROUP BY v.EMP_ID
    ORDER BY MIN(WHICH);
```